# Run ant command from shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a script to automate compilation of java projects, and using ant for the same. When I run the ant command directly in bash shell it builds the project properly. However, if I run the exact same command from a shell script, I'm getting the following error:

```
./build.sh: line 21: Apache: command not found
```

Line 21 in my build.sh file is:

```
`ant clean build -v -buildfile $BUILDFILE`
```

where `$BUILDFILE=auto_build.xml`.

I've also added the path to ant bin folder in .bashrc
`$ANT_HOME` has the value `/usr/share/ant`

`ant -version` gives me `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014` (This command also does not work if added to a shell script)

Comment: What is the running environment of your script? can you print `which ant` in your script to verify that you running the right ant command.

Comment: `which ant=/usr/share/ant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is due to the backticks around the command. Try replacing

```
`ant clean build -v -buildfile $BUILDFILE`
```

with

```
ant clean build -v -buildfile $BUILDFILE
```

The backticks indicate that the bash interpreter should execute the *output* of the `ant` command as a command by itself.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash.

Comment: This was the case indeed. This is my first time writing shell scripts and I got confused about when to use backticks. Still got quite a bit to learn, I guess. Will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to. :)